# freeipmi - ipmimonitoring_sensors returning internal ipmi error

Tags: ipmi

I am executing the ipmimonitoring-sensors.c example provided in the freeipmi library.
It throws internal error sometimes. Issue is reproducible when i execute the program back to back couple of times.  I need to wait approximately 30 sec after the last execution for the program to run properly. Has anyone faced this issue before? If yes, can you tell me how to avoid it.

This is the error **ipmi_monitoring_sensor_readings_by_record_id: internal error**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FreeIPMI maintainer here.  The "internal error" indicates some logical error that the library doesn't know how to handle.  Given its coming from  **ipmi_monitoring_sensor_readings_by_record_id** and it occurs when you run the program back to back, I would bet there is some internal IPMI issue on your system.

Perhaps the motherboard has some issue with a high amount of IPMI traffic or a sensor has issues with a high number of requests.  Many of these situations are handled more gracefully (perhaps give a BUSY error or minimally SYSTEM error), but perhaps there is some combo of error situations I haven't yet seen.  (Lots of motherboards return errors that would be considered non-standard or unexpected).

If you're interested in working through that, just send something onto the FreeIPMI mailing list.

Comment: If there was any motherboard or sensor issues, wouldn't the commands also show the same error when executed?
I ran some of the commands on terminal back to back , including ipmi-sensors with group option, it didn't throw any error

Comment: Good point.  They aren't 100% identical, but they are close.  Perhaps it's a subtle bug somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Set the driver_type = -1 (for default) and it works.

Comment: Just adding a bit more info.  The default driver type in the ipmimonitoring-sensors example is coded to be the "KVS" driver.  But if the system uses a different one (e.g. linux /dev/ipmi0), things can conflict.  User can set to the driver type to the correct one for the system (e.g. IPMI_MONITORING_DRIVER_TYPE_OPENIPMI).  If driver type is -1 it will tell libipmimonitoring to look for an appropriate driver.